# Unable to install node modules due to dependency conflict

Tags: javascript, npm

I am unable to install node modules of the project,
On executing npm i command this error is produced

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-io-example@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@6.1.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"6.1.10" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"7.2.16" from @angular/common@7.2.16
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^7.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"\>=7.0.0" from @angular/cdk@7.3.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^7.0.0-beta.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /home/trd-devteam/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/trd-devteam/.npm/\_logs/2023-05-29T08_39_44_326Z-debug.log
```

What i tried:
Tried using npm i --legacy-peers-deps and npm i --force
Getting the following error

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/trd-devteam/bharat/trd_optimized/node_modules/grpc
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/home/trd-devteam/bharat/trd_optimized/node_modules/grpc/build'
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/avl/avl.o ...
...
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens quite a lot these days
So follow the below steps to clean up the npm:

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder.
2. Delete the `package-lock.json`.
3. Clean the npm cache with the following:

   `npm cache clean --force`
4. Install the project’s dependencies via npm with

   `npm install`

Comment: I`m getting the same error